# Angular 2: Cannot find name 'Params'

Tags: angular, lambda, routes, subscribe

When subscribing to the parameters of ActivatedRoute, I get the error **Cannot find name 'Params'**. From which package do I import it from?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from '../../services/recipe/recipe.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

**// I'm missing an import here. Just don't know which package to load from.**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-detail',
  templateUrl: './recipe-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-detail.component.css']
})
export class RecipeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  recipe: Recipe;
  id: number;

  constructor (
    private rService: RecipeService ,
    private ACTIVATED_ROUTE: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.ACTIVATED_ROUTE.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.ACTIVATED_ROUTE.params.subscribe(
      ( P: Params ) => { // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PROBLEM LINE
        this.id = +P['id'];
        this.recipe = this.rService.getRecipe( this.id );
      }
    );
  }

  onAddToShopList(){
    this.rService.addIngredientsToShopList( this.recipe.ingredients );
  }

}
```

I searched the documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/router
I've checked all **25** instances of "Params" on said page.
I've checked all **301** instances of "import" on the same page.
At no point is "Params" ever imported.

This works fine without the import:

```
 (P)=> {...}
```

This leads to error:

```
(P:Params)=>{...} ?
```

The **question is about the type of "P"** not the type of `ACTIVATED_ROUTE.params`, which is a `Observable<Param>`.

Comment: It says right at the top of the [docs page](https://angular.io/api/router/Params).

Comment: You are mistaken. 

The type of "P" in my question
is neither the Observable<Params> or ParamMap
types mentioned on page:
https://angular.io/guide/router
I checked all 25 instances of "Params" on said page.

In addition, I have checked all 301 instances of
"import" on the same page.

At no point is "Params" imported.

Perhaps you are using an untyped expression
such as:  (P)=> {...} instead of (P:Params)=>{...} ?

Comment: I literally linked to the page in question, *for `Params`*, in the comment. Also yes, you could use it without the explicit type, as the subscription to the activated route's `params` *must* be `Params`. I never said it was either of those types (although `params` *is*, of course, of `Observable<Params>`, hence the subscription being `Params`).

Comment: Fair. It is in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Why would people down vote him for asking a question???

Answer (score 5):

Missing Import:

```
import { Params } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: No clue. But wasn't me as I can't vote on answers to my question.